# How do I return a value immediately on a Spring Webflux controller then do extra processing?

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux

I have a `@PostMapping`

```
@PostMapping(value = "/formData",
        consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public Observation submitFormData(
        @RequestHeader(JwtAssertionInterceptor.X_JWT_ASSERTION) final String jwtAssertion,
        @RequestBody final String formDataJson) throws MalformedClaimException {

  ... do something really slow here ...
  return Observation.empty(); // this does not need anything from the processing above.
```

}

I want to do something like this

```
@PostMapping(value = "/formData",
        consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public Observation submitFormData(
        @RequestHeader(JwtAssertionInterceptor.X_JWT_ASSERTION) final String jwtAssertion,
        @RequestBody final String formDataJson) throws MalformedClaimException {

  return Observation.empty(); // this does not need anything from the processing above.

  ... do something really slow here ...
```

}

So what we have done is

```
@PostMapping(value = "/formData",
        consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public Observation submitFormData(
        @RequestHeader(JwtAssertionInterceptor.X_JWT_ASSERTION) final String jwtAssertion,
        @RequestBody final String formDataJson) throws MalformedClaimException {

  Thread t = new Thread(()->       ... do something really slow here ... );
  t.start();
  return Observation.empty(); // this does not need anything from the processing above.
```

}

However, I want to know if we can do this through `Mono`s and not do any thread management on our code base.  I'd also like to avoid `@Async` because I want it to not run too many threads.

Answer (score 2):

1. return a `Mono` version of the result
2. in the `Mono` add a `doOnSubscribe(...)` handler which will get triggered when the Mono is subscribed which happens when returning the response to the client.

```java
@PostMapping(value = "/formData",
        consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public Mono<Observation> submitFormData(
        @RequestHeader(JwtAssertionInterceptor.X_JWT_ASSERTION) final String jwtAssertion,
        @RequestBody final String formDataJson) throws MalformedClaimException {

        return Mono.just(Observation.empty())
                .doOnSubscribe((subscription) -> {
                    really slow thing
                });
```